# how to make your code running when app is terminated in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, background

I want my flutter app to receive notification from my rest api and flutter local notifications plugin
without firebase, workmanager or foreground services. If any has a solution help me please.

```
void get Notifications()async{
  var Notifications = await Db.get("notifications","/*Notification id*/");
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show();
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it without WorkManager or ForegroundService when your app is closed. If you want to do it anyway then you must open app and then start your service.

Comment: Both workmanager and foregroundservices has default notification that stays in the notification bar until you stop working it how can I hide that default notification.

Comment: Android has stopped the background service running when app is killed or in background because of security reasons so you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [Cron Package](https://pub.dev/packages/cron).

1.Add the cron package to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  cron: ^x.x.x  # Replace with the latest version
```

2.Import the necessary packages in your Dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cron/cron.dart';
```

3.Define a function that will be executed at the specified time:

```
void myTask() {
  // Your task to be executed
  // This code will be executed according to the cron expression
  // Perform your desired operations here
}
```

4.Schedule the task using the cron package:

```
void scheduleCronTask() {
  final cron = Cron();

  // Schedule the task using a cron expression
  // The example below will run the task every day at 12 am
  cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('0 0 * * *'), myTask);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());

  // Schedule the cron task
  scheduleCronTask();
}
```